# Map function to recast an array

Tags: swift

Below is the code that works:

```
let aProvider: () -> [aParticipant] = {
    let results = fetchRequestController.fetchedObjects as! [ParticipantFetchResultsProtocol]

    var newArray: Array<aParticipant> = Array()
    for result in results {
        let obj = result as aParticipant
        newArray.append(obj)
    }

    return newArray
}
```

With map I tried:

```
var newArray = results.map({aParticipant($0)})
```

I get an error: `aParticipant cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Is there a way to accomplish this with `map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're using `as` to upcast `result` to `aParticipant` in your `for` loop, you can simply do the same in a `map`. Assuming `AParticipant` is a protocol (sounds like the case from the error you're getting), you just want:

```
let newArray = results.map { $0 as AParticipant }
```

Or you can let Swift infer the upcast:

```
let newArray : [AParticipant] = results.map { $0 }
```

However, if `AParticipant` is a superclass type of the elements in your `results` array, as [Alexander Momchliov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776364/map-function-to-recast-an-array/38776542?noredirect=1#comment64926308_38776542) notes, you can simplify this down to:

```
let newArray = results as [AParticipant]
```

An explicit `map` is required for protocol types however, as they have a different memory structure and therefore each element needs to be converted individually. See both [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any) and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387256/type-conversion-when-using-protocol-in-swift) for more info.

Also note that I've capitalised `AParticipant`, as types should be `UpperCamelCase` – as per the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Comment: Isn't this a case where `as [AParticipant]` can work?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Depends what `AParticipant` is – if it's a protocol, then no it'll require `map` as abstract types have a different memory structure, so an O(n) walk will be required to cast each individual element. If it's just a superclass, then you're indeed right that this could be handled implicitly by the array, I'll update my answer to note this.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I suspected. To be honest I just always try a cast, see if the compiler yells at me, and then map :p

Answer (score 0):

You can actually collapse the function into a one liner:

return fetchRequestController.fetchedObjects.map { $0 as! Participant }