# Swift cannot implicitly infer protocol conformance of Enum when passed as array in some cases

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, protocols, swift-protocols

When using the variable `all` in the Enum `MotorVehicle` in order to pass all enum cases, the code does not compile. But doing the same thing witnout using said variable works. Why is this? I want to make the Enum "aware" of all its cases, not having to create arrays of it everywhere, or having to use "map". And using the solution with the variable `allAsProtocol` (used by version 7) is just plain ugly IMHO. Any ideas?

**Swift 2.2 code** (just paste the code below in a Playground)

```
    protocol Motorized {
        func startEngine()
    }

    enum MotorVehicle: String, Motorized {
        case Car
        case MotorCycle

        static var all: [MotorVehicle] {
            return [.Car, .MotorCycle]
        }

        static var allAsProtocol: [Motorized] {
            return [MotorVehicle.Car, MotorVehicle.MotorCycle]
        }

        func startEngine() {
            print("Starting \(self.rawValue)")
        }
    }

    func start(motorized motorized: [Motorized]) {
        for motor in motorized {
            start(motorized: motor)
        }
    }

    func start(motorized motorized: Motorized) {
        motorized.startEngine()
    }

    // VERSION 1
    start(motorized: MotorVehicle.Car) //works

    // VERSION 2
    start(motorized: [MotorVehicle.Car, MotorVehicle.MotorCycle]) //works

    // VERSION 3
    /* In my opinion, this is logically identical to the code at the previous line...  */
    start(motorized: MotorVehicle.all) //Compilation Error - Cannot convert value of type ‘[MotorVehicle]’ to expected argument type ‘[Motorized]'

    // VERSION 4
    start(motorized: (MotorVehicle.all as! [Motorized])) //Compilation Error - 'Motorized' is not a subtype of 'MotorVehicle'

    // VERSION 5
    start(motorized: (MotorVehicle.all as [Motorized])) //Compilation Error - cannot convert value of type [MotorVehicle] to type [Motorized] in coercion

    // VERSION 6
    start(motorized: (MotorVehicle.all.map { return $0 as Motorized } )) //works

    // VERSION 7
    start(motorized: MotorVehicle.allAsProtocol) //works
```

Comment: See both [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any) and [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387256/type-conversion-when-using-protocol-in-swift). It all starts with the fact that generics are invariant in Swift, therefore `[MotorVehicle]` is seen as a completely unrelated type to `[Motorized]`. Although `Array` can perform some implicit 'under the hood' conversions between array types, it requires an explicit conversion (via `map`) to an array of abstract type, as this conversion is potentially expensive.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, makes sense... But can you come up with any better solution than the one used on Version 6 or 7? Is there any more elegant solution? :)

Comment: Because `map` can infer the `as Motorized` from the context, and because you don't need an explicit `return` in a single expression closure, you could simplify the call down to `start(motorized: MotorVehicle.all.map{$0})`.

Comment: @Hamish wow okay, so the compiler can infer the protocol conformance by writing MotorVehicle.all.map{$0}), that's a bit odd, but much nicer syntax, thanks!

Comment: No problem :) It works because the compiler can see that `start(_:)` expects a `[Motorized]` argument, therefore it can infer that the generic parameter `T` in the `map(_:)` call is `Motorized`, therefore it can implicitly upcast each element from `MotorVehicle` to `Motorized` (and because of the conformance, this satisfies the type inference engine).