# Swift 3 unable to append array of objects, which conform to a protocol, to a collection of that protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, protocols

Below I have pasted code which you should be able to paste into a Swift 3 playground and see the error.

I have a protocol defined and create an empty array of that type.  I then have a class which conforms to the protocol which I try to append to the array but I get the below error.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var text: String { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var text = "Hello"
}
var collection = [MyProtocol]()
var myClassCollection = [MyClass(), MyClass()]
collection.append(myClassCollection)

argument type '[MyClass]' does not conform to expected type 'MyProtocol'
```

Note that collection += myClassCollection returns the following error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type '[MyProtocol]' to expected argument type 'inout _'
```

This was working in earlier versions of Swift.

The only solution I have found so far is to iterate and add each element to the new array like so:

```
for item in myClassCollection {
    collection.append(item)
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

The solution as show below is:

```
collection.append(contentsOf: myClassCollection as [MyProtocol])
```

The real issue is a misleading compiler error when you are missing "as [MyProtocol]"

The compiler error reads:

```
error: extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call
collection.append(contentsOf: myClassCollection)
```

This error causes users to remove `contentsOf:` from the code which then causes the error I first mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`append(_ newElement: Element)` appends a single element.
What you want is `append(contentsOf newElements: C)`.

But you have
to *convert* the `[MyClass]` array to `[MyProtocol]` explicitly:

```
collection.append(contentsOf: myClassCollection as [MyProtocol])
// or:
collection += myClassCollection as [MyProtocol]
```

As explained in [Type conversion when using protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387256/type-conversion-when-using-protocol-in-swift/38387367#38387367), this
wraps each array element into a box which holds "something that conforms to `MyProtocol`", it is not just a reinterpretation
of the array.

The compiler does this automatically for a single value (that is why

```
for item in myClassCollection {
    collection.append(item)
}
```

compiles) but not for an array. In earlier Swift versions, you
could not even cast an entire array with `as [MyProtocol]`, you
had to cast each individual element.

Comment: This works.  collection.append(contentsOf: myClassCollection as [MyProtocol])  The error is misleading if you have are missing as [MyProtocol].  The error reads extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to append an array when collection is only expecting individual items. For example, changing collection to this compiles:

```
var collection = [[MyProtocol]]()
```

here is a way you can go about adding two arrays together:

```
func merge<T: MyProtocol>(items: inout [T], with otherItems: inout [T]) -> [T] {
return items + otherItems
```

}

```
var myClassCollection = [MyClass(), MyClass()]

var myClassCollection2 = [MyClass(), MyClass()]

let combinedArray = merge(items: &myClassCollection, with: &myClassCollection2)
```