# Getting "extraneous argument label" when trying to append array to other array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, compiler-errors, append

I'm getting `extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call
array.append(contentsOf: test)` error when trying to run this code in playground:

```
import Cocoa

var array:[Any] = []
let test = [""]
array.append(contentsOf: [""])
array.append(contentsOf: test)
```

Why is this happening? As I understand, there are two equal arrays with empty string.

Comment: just declare test as `let test:[Any] = [""]` and it will stop complaining. Another option is to change the array type `var array:[String] = []`

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/41096163/2976878

Comment: `test` (which has type `[String]`) has to be converted to `[Any]` before it can be appended. This process requires each constituent `String` be boxed into a protocol witness table. Since it's an `O(n)` operation, it's probably best that the compiler doesn't silently do this without informing you that such a conversion is happening.

Comment: Check if you have any typos or confused case-insensitivity variables somewhere in the array

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To answer your specific question in the comments, in that case you just need to cast so Swift knows you're aware. In this case since `SKShapeNode` downcasts to `SKNode` just fine, you can just cast with `as`. If you were doing a cast that may fail, you'd need to use `as?` and safely unwrap to be sure.

```
var allNodes: [SKNode] = []
let onlyShapeNodes: [SKShapeNode] = []

allNodes.append(contentsOf: onlyShapeNodes as [SKNode])
```

For the original generic example this would work as well.

```
var array: [Any] = []
let test = ["", ""]

array.append(contentsOf: [""] as [Any])
array.append(contentsOf: test as [Any])
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I mistakenly thought that since SKShapeNode is inherited from SKNode, I can easily add an array of SKShapeNodes to the SKNodes array without any "as" usage. Especially I was confused by the fact that I still can write something like
```array.append (SKShapeNode ())```, where ```array``` is ```[SKNode]```- and add one SKShapeNode with no errors

Comment: Yea in some cases the compiler can infer what you're trying to do such as `array.append(SKShapeNode())` where others it can't because the type is explicit. This happens a lot with numbers too. `1 + 5.0` works but if you put them into variables and did `valueInt + valueDouble` it would get mad. Because the types are saved at that point.

Comment: Anyway, this is very strange. Just look at my original question code. Now I don't understand other thing. If we need to cast ```test``` to ```[Any]```, why we don't need to cast ```[""]``` to ```Any``` like this: ```array.append(contentsOf: [""] as [Any])```? I saw that it was in your answer. But in the first case everything works without ```as [Any]```

Comment: In other words: append ```test``` - error. Append ```test as [Any]``` - ok. But append ```[""]``` - ok, and append  ```[""] as [Any]``` is ok too...

Comment: Because similar to putting `SKShapeNode()` directly in it can infer the type of `[""]` if its passed directly in.